# How to solve $x+3+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)(x^2-x+2)+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

solve the equalition
$$x+3+\sqrt[3]{(x+1)(x^2-x+2)+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}}+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}=0$$

I have seen some methods, for this problem.

my idea:
let $\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}=y,$ then
$\sqrt[3]{y^3+y+1}+y=-x-3$

and following have nice methods? thank you everyone.

Comment: This is *not* a differential equation. Please edit the tags.

Comment: yes,I find this why the tags not  equation,Thank you

Comment: Have you tried : cubing $\sqrt[3]{y^3+y+1}=-x-3-y$ ?

Comment: I have tried,then we have $$y^3+y+1=-(y+3+x)^3$$,then follow is very ugly.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** lhs of the equation is a strictly increasing function, so there is at most one root which is easy to guess.

Comment: Is it obvious the left side is increasing?

Comment: $((x+1)(x^2-x+2))'=1+3x^2>0$. The rest is clear, isn't it?

Comment: OK, my fault, I missed a term.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note also that the form which OP implicitly achieves $x+3+\sqrt[3]{y^3+y+1}+y=0$ has $y$ increasing with $x$ and makes it obvious that the function is increasing.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x+1}$ and $z=\sqrt[3]{y^3+y+1}$, then we translate the original equation into$$x+y+z+3=0$$ by following the procedure in the original post. We also have, by direct calculation:

$$z^3=y^3+y+1=x^3+x+1+y+1$$ so that $$z^3+z+1=x^3+(x+y+z+3)=x^3$$  So we have the suggestive equations$$y^3=x^3+x+1$$$$z^3=y^3+y+1$$$$x^3=z^3+z+1$$

From which we would immediately guess $x=y=z$ and $=-1$ follows immediately.

---

Suppose the three values are not equal and wlog that $y\gt x$, with $x$ being the least value, then (using the first of the three equations) $$(y-x)(x^2+xy+y^2)=x+1$$ The left-hand side is the product of two positive factors* so we have  $x\gt -1$ and ($x$ being the least value, and values being unequal) $x+y+z\gt -3$, which is a contradiction.

---

For * note $$x^2+xy+y^2=(x+\frac y2)^2+\frac {3y^2}4$$

Comment: Note also that once we have the strict inequalities $y>x>-1$ we have also $z^3-y^3=y+1>0$ so that $z>y>-1$ and $x^3-z^3>z+1>0$ so that $x>z>y>x$ which is a contradiction. So the only possible solution to the three equations is $x=y=z=-1$ - once we have those equations we don't need $x+y+z+3=0$.